Error cross compiling on windows 64 bit to x86 32bit with i368-gcc - "Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef ignored."
I'm trying to make a simple os that uses the x86 32 bit architecture,
my kernel is the following: kernel.c:
void dummy_test_entrypoint() {
}

void main() {
    char* video_memory = (char*) 0xb8000;
    *video_memory = 'X';
}

and im trying to cross compile it with the following command
i386-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
but I get the following error:
C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/cc6RjRAx.s:4: Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef ignored.
C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/cc6RjRAx.s:4: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `d'
C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/cc6RjRAx.s:20: Warning: .size pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef ignored.
C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/cc6RjRAx.s:20: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `d'
C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/cc6RjRAx.s:22: Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef ignored.
C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/cc6RjRAx.s:22: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `m'
C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/cc6RjRAx.s:42: Warning: .size pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef ignored.
C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/cc6RjRAx.s:42: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `m'

I've tried to compile the code with just gcc, but then I get the following error when linking:
i386-elf-ld -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o --oformat binary
i386-elf-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00001000
kernel_entry.o:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `main'
kernel.o:kernel.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `__alloca'
kernel.o:kernel.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `___main'

if it helps im trying to follow this tutorial:
https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/tree/master/13-kernel-barebones
